# Query Active Directory for all accounts with expiry date set

Tags: batch-file, active-directory

I'm trying to run a script in order to have a list of Users with the expiry date set, So where expiry date Doesn't equal "never" (from what i understand of AD)

I'm doing it for all disabled users with the following code

```
dsquery user -limit 0 -disabled
```

I understand there's some filters you can use with dsquery to get this?

edit: i know that i could look for all users. get the expire date attribute and filter after that. but i assume anything built into dsquery would be more efficient.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LDIFDE.EXE yout can use :

```
ldifde  -f c:\temp\expiry.ldf -d "OU=SomeOU,DC=Domain,DC=domainRoot" -r "(&(objectclass=user)(!(accountExpires=9223372036854775807)))" -l accountExpires
```

**accountExpires** is he date when the account expires. This value represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). A value of 0 or 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9223372036854775807) indicates that the account never expires.

You will find [here](http://www.silogix.fr/conversion-dentiers-64-bits-en-dates-relative-ou-absolue.aspx) a graphical tool that allow you to read te value.